How to use pyspark regex to correctly break data with pipe delimited with literal pipe inside?
I have a raw databricks table with a single column named "value" which the data is from a CSV with pipe delimited.
The data inside this single column is 5 fields.
The field3 content is a json which contains PIPE inside.
The data looks like:
10|20|{"menu":{"id":"file","menuitem":[{"value":"New","onclick":"CreateNewDoc() || ReplaceDoc() || DeleteDoc()"}]}}|13123|344234

I'm new to pyspark and my data is massive, so i've tried to break the content to a new 5 columns table, using regex in the field 3 with no sucess.
My code looks like:
from pyspark.sql.functions import split, col, regexp_extract
from pyspark.sql.functions import DataFrame


df = spark.sql(
"""
select value from my_table
"""
)

df_out = df.withColumn(field1, split(col("value", "\\|".getItem(0))
           .withColumn(field2, split(col("value", "\\|".getItem(1))
           .withColumn(field3, regex_extract("value", r"\|\{(.*?)\}\|",1))
           .withColumn(field4, split(col("value", "\\|".getItem(3))
           .withColumn(field5, split(col("value", "\\|".getItem(4))

new_table = df_out.select("field1", "field2", "field3", "field4", "field5")

new_table.display()

My result from this code is like some part of the json in field3 break incorrectly to field4 and field5.
Someone can help me to solve this problem? 
Maybe consider all between the first { and the last } and treat anything inside as literal?
Thank you!

Typo: withColunm should be withColumn

Why do you keep undoing my formatting of the input data?

Sorry, not really familiarized with stackoverflow posts bro.

I don't think there's any reliable way to do what you want. There's no easy way to distinguish the pipes that are delimiters and the ones that are literal. You should fix the data format so it can be parsed properly.

Fix the data is actually my job as Data Engineer as in the origin it wouldn't correct. My literal pipes is the pipes that are enclosed by {}, maybe some regex that consider all inside {} as literal should solve. The problem is i don't know how to do :(

Regular expressions are not good at distinguishing "inside" from "outside". What if there are other {} characters in that field?

E.g. {"value":"New}", ...}

Regular expressions also can't easily detect balanced braces. So the regexp can't tell that the nested objects aren't ending the outer object.

Regex would be used to check the first ocurrence of "{" and the last ocurrence of "}", so the entire inside is literal. Anyway, thats i think, if could be do in a diferent way, no problem.

It looks like you have .getItem() in the wrong place. It should be split(...).getItem(...)

@Barmar it works bro, thank you so much!!!

For the columns after the JSON field, count from the end rather than the beginning, so the pipes in the JSON don't cause the indexes to be wrong.
fields = split(col("value"), r'\|')
nfields = size(fields)
df_out = df.withColumn(field1, fields.getItem(0))
           .withColumn(field2, fields.getItem(1))
           .withColumn(field3, regexp_extract(col("value"), r"\|\{(.*?)\}\|",1))
           .withColumn(field4, fields.getItem(nfields-2))
           .withColumn(field5, fields.getItem(nfields-1))

